# R xml2 parent ancestor for each relevant node

Tags: r, xml, xpath, xml2

Is there any way to directly e.g. get the text of a parent of each node of a set of nodes?

I am accessing an `xml` file through the `R` library `xml2`. Using the `xml_find_all()` function is highly efficient but I also want to extract some parents attributes for each found node. When applying `xml_find_all()` on the set of nodes I don't get the respective parent node for each relevant node but just the set of relevant parent nodes which is smaller than the set of relevant child nodes and there is no way to match them.

Of course it is possible to access each node and then go through a for loop, looking for the respective parent but this slows down the overall process.

Comment: ??xml_parents()

Comment: xml_parents will provide a set of all parents up to the root of a node or a set of nodes.

Comment: In theory, `xml_find_first` (replacement for the obsolete `xml_find_one`) should do this.
But in the recent package, they changed its behavior, hopefully by mistake.
See this issue https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/issues/194